# jQuery auto loading from a page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page on my forums that I am trying to get to automatically update when there is a new post, however it only seems to work intermittently.

I have a feeling that it could be the order of which success and wait are but cannot for the life of me figure it out, could someone a but more knowledgeable see where I am going wrong?

Thanks

```
<script>
var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

function myTimer() {
$.ajax({
url: 'loadtopic.php?id=<? echo $getid; ?>&time=' + timestamp,
success: function(data) {
    $("#append").before(data);
    setTimeout(myTimer,3000);
    timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
}
}); 
}
myTimer();
</script>
```

Comment: dont use setTimeout inside the ajax request, also you can use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to create a timed poll to load new posts.

Comment: Actually, using a timeout in the success handler seems like the best way to do that ?

Comment: When the update fails, what do you see in the developer console of your favorite web browser? Is the server returning an error? Or is the data simply bad?

Comment: What you should be doing is checking that `data` is not the same as the content that is already there, so you don't keep adding the same stuff, unless you somehow are solving that on the serverside.

Comment: There isn't an issue with the data it loads all new posts with the post date greater than unixtimestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request fails for any reason, success will not be called and so the loop will break.
You can use setInterval to ensure it is called.

```
<script>
var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

function myTimer() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'loadtopic.php?id=<? echo $getid; ?>&time=' + timestamp,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#append").before(data);
      timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    }
  }); 
}
myTimer();
setInterval(myTimer,3000);
</script>
```

Otherwise put setTimeout into the 'complete' option and the code will be executed even if the request fails.

```
<script>
var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

function myTimer() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'loadtopic.php?id=<? echo $getid; ?>&time=' + timestamp,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#append").before(data);
      timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(myTimer,3000);
    }
  }); 
}
myTimer();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it:

1. Create a global (or hide this whole thing somewhere) variable that
   stores the last time the page updated or loaded. `window.latest_update = new Date()`
2. Create a function that gets new posts from the server based on the
   current timestamp.
3. Run that function on an interval and request only posts since the
   latest timestamp. Probably between 20 and 40 seconds- but optimize
   based on your server load. `var PollServer = setInterval(get_posts, 20000)`
4. Have a separate function that you can call to load posts onto the page. This will allow      you to keep your code kinda modular.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your code:

```
<script> 
function myTimer() {
   var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
   $.ajax({
      url: 'loadtopic.php?id=<? echo $getid; ?>&time=' + timestamp,
      success: function(data) {
         $("#append").before(data);
         setTimeout(myTimer,3000);

      }
   }); 
}

myTimer();
</script>
```

Comment: that won't do it as it its setting the timestamp before it loads the posts so it will never load new ones.

Comment: Why not? When ajax call success and call Timeout, the next time myTimer is fired timestamp will be updated for the new ajax call.

Comment: each time it calls mytimer it sets the timestamp to what it is now, then goes on to load posts from now. It needs to load posts from the last saved variable of timestamp so can see if there are posts between them and the next call.